# python's tarfile.extractall creates superfluous files

Tags: python, tarfile

I'm using Python's `tarfile` module to extract a `.tar.gz` file.

The problem is that for every file `foo.bar` in my archive, an additional file `._foo.bar` is also created, and I can't figure out why.

my code looks like that:

```
import tarfile
tar_ref = tarfile.open('file.tar.gz', 'r:gz')
tar_ref.extractall('directory')
tar_ref.close()
```

and for the following archive:

```
file.tar.gz
|-file1
|-file2
|-directory
  |-file3
```

I get the following file structure:

```
directory
|-file1
|-._file1
|-file2
|-._file2
|-directory
  |-file3
  |-._file3
|-._directory
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Never seen this problem on my Mac, but it could relate to [this issue](https://www.cnet.com/news/invisible-files-with-prefix-are-created-on-some-shared-volumes-and-external-disks/).

Comment: Seems like it might be related, but it only happens when I un-tar using Python, never when I do using the terminal

Comment: I'm getting the same trash and I'm simply removing them by `[os.remove(spurious_file) for spurious_file in glob(LOCAL_TEST_DATA_STORAGE_PATH+"/**/._*", recursive=True)]`